# After upgrading vim to 9.1506 problem with console. vim-9.0 o.K

Tags: console

When I'm in vim (no problem with gvim), change the console (maybe inserting some text marked with <kbd>F5</kbd> in another application) and return to the first console with vim I get garbage with the mouse and the keyboard (cursor o.k.). Even if I kill vim, the console is unusable. I have to close it.

My version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28 kompiliert am May  3 2023 00:37:20)
Inklusive der Patches: 1-1506
Übersetzt von ad08@mspckad
Riesige Version mit GTK2 GUI.
 Ein- (+) oder ausschließlich (-) der Eigenschaften:
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
+browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
+clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con_gui    +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            +X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
+dnd               +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       +xpm
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static    
          System-vimrc-Datei: "$VIM/vimrc"
        Benutzer-vimrc-Datei: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 zweite Benutzer-vimrc-Datei: "~/.vim/vimrc"
         Benutzer-exrc-Datei: "$HOME/.exrc"
         System-gvimrc-Datei: "$VIM/gvimrc"
       Benutzer-gvimrc-Datei: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
zweite Benutzer-gvimrc-Datei: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
      defaults Datei: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
           System-Menü-Datei: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
     Voreinstellung für $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Übersetzt: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Linken: gcc -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -ltinfo -lelf -lrt -ldl -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE -L/usr/local/lib64 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE -lperl -lm -ldl -lcrypt -lpthread -L/usr/local/bin/python3-config -lpython3.8
```

Comment: How did you "change the console"? By `:sh`? or `:term`? or `C-z`? What operating system are you using?

Comment: I change the console with the mouse (2 consoles side by side or in another window). It doesn't matter. My system is openSUSE Leap 15.1 (Linux).

Comment: what terminal? What kind of garbage (paste a screenshot please)? What exactly is `f5` doing? Does it happen using `vim --clean`?

Comment: My terminal is from konsole.kde.org, Konsole version 18.12.3. Pressing F5 is irrelevant for the problem, its an example only. The same problem is with vim --clean. I've made 2 screenshots but don't know how to include.

Comment: You should use Vim's issue tracker.